# Kotlin : Why *unresolved reference* for a constructor parameter of a subclass of a sealed class

Tags: kotlin, parameters, constructor, scope, sealed-class

```
sealed class Person () {
    data class Man (val name: String): Person()
    data class Woman (val name: String): Person() 

    fun stringOf(): String {
    return when (this) {
        is Person.Man -> "Mr "+this.name
        is Person.Woman -> "Mrs "+this.name
    }
    } // works fine

    fun nameOf() : String {
        return this.name // error: unresolved reference: name
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val man = Person.Man("John Smith")
    println (man.stringOf()) 
}
```

Why the code above gives *error: unresolved reference: name* for the function *nameOf* and works correctly for function *stringOf* which looks very similar.

Comment: Because it is not smart-casted to an actual type that actually has `name`. Why not move it to `Person`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I want to get *name* constructor of the data classes, the sealed class has no constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no `name` property is defined in `Person` class. All `name`s you have are in subclasses, so `nameOf` function in the parent class cannot access it.